# Segfault from using std::sort on vector<pair<string, int>>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, gdb

I am writing a c++ program that counts occurrence of distinct strings in a given file. I use std::sort to sort it in descending order of the second field (int).

```
...

bool compare(const std::pair<std::string, int> &p1, const std::pair<std::string, int> &p2) {
    if (p1.second < p2.second) return false;
    return true;
}

TC::TC(const std::vector<std::string> &collection) {
    ...
    // iterating through collection with iterator "it", and push_back a pair when unique string found
    std::pair<std::string, int> temp = {*it, std::count(collection.begin(), collection.end(), *it)};
  counts.push_back(temp);


    // calling std::sort to sort descending order of the field "second"
    std::sort(counts.begin(), counts.end(), &compare);
```

Yet, when I test on a sample file (that I can pass as an argument to main), I get segfault. And, from looking into gdb, following shows up:

```
47      if (p1.second < p2.second) {
(gdb) p p1
$14 = (const std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> &) @0x61c520: {first = "namespace", second = 1}

...
(gdb) p p1
$16 = (const std::pair<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> &) @0x61c500: {first = {static npos = <optimized out>, 
_M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x61ec88 "sep"}}, second = 1}
```

It appears to me that the field "first" of some pairs went out of scope and became garbage if I am interpreting that "<__gnu_css..... _M_p" correctly. However, I am confused why such would happen since push_back will create a new copy of pair of new string and int. So it should not be garbage. This is my first post and I am still novice in c++, so please let me know if anything doesn't seem clear.

Comment: Slightly OT, but why don't you use a `map<string, size_t>`?

Comment: Is map better since map is essentially storing std::pair<string, bool>? does map perform better than vector?

Comment: Why would the map only store a pair with `bool` as data? @Biffen said `size_t`. And if you have a map it's very easy to do just e.g. `word = getNextWord(); myMap[word]++;` instead of first finding the word in the vector to increment the second value of the pair. The only problem is sorting, but that can be solved by copying the data to a vector and sort it. As for performance, I don't think it will do worse.

Comment: @221tao Er, where did `bool` come from? And it's not about performance, it's about choosing the appropriate container. A map stores pairs, but makes sure that the keys are unique, so that you don't have to. As for the value type, do you need it to be signed? Can there be a negative occurrence of a word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`compare` is somehow messed up and doesn't meet the requirements of [`Compare`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). Throw away the branching and simply do:

```
return p1.second > p2.second;
```

to sort in descending order. What you have is essentially a `>=`, which violates:

> - For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`
> - If `comp(a,b)==true` then `comp(b,a)==false`

and this results in undefined behavior.